# How to Mock instanceof in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a piece of code, what I want test with Mockito:

```
mockedClass instanceof SampleInterface
```

The `mockedClass` is mocked abstract class: `MockedClass`  , and the  `SampleInterface` is an Interface. This is the failing point:

```
Validate.isTrue(mockedClass instanceof SampleInterface, "The mockedClass is not a SampleInterface");
```

How to mock this code?

Comment: Just to clarify, `mockedClass` is a mock-instance of type `MockedClass` (i.e. `mock(MockedClass.class)`) and `MockClass` implements `SampleInterface`?

Comment: The class what implements mockedClass implements this the SampleInterface.
I didn't wrote an important info: That mockedClass is an Abstract class, mocked like mock(MockedClass.class).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It sounds like you need [`MockSettings.extraInterfaces`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#extraInterfaces-java.lang.Class...-).

```
MockedClass mockedClass = mock(MockedClass.class,
    withSettings().extraInterfaces(SampleInterface.class));
```

Note that it comes with its own warning label:

> This mysterious feature should be used very occasionally. The object under test should know exactly its collaborators & dependencies. If you happen to use it often than [sic] please make sure you are really producing simple, clean & readable code.

As an alternative, create an interface for testing that extends all of the interfaces you want your mock to implement, and mock that the usual way.

```
public abstract class ForTest implements SampleInterface {}

MockedClass mockedClass = mock(ForTest.class);
```

Comment: withSettings() won't compile. I think I am using an older version of Mockito where withSettings() wasn't available.

Comment: BUT this is what I searched for!

Comment: Glad to help! Those features are new as of Mockito 1.8, from around 2009, so it may be worth upgrading to. The latest Mockito release is 1.10, and 2.0 is coming out shortly.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer:

If possible, you should instead mock the interface, meaning create the mock like this:

```
SampleInterface mockedClass = mock(SampleInterface.class); // not mock(MockedClass)
```

Comment: That is worth a try.