# Mock the isAssignableFrom()

Tags: java, mockito

I am having two java class as below,

```
public class Class1{
    private Object actionObject;    
    public Object getActionObject() {
        return actionObject;
    }
    public void setActionObject(Object actionObject) {
        this.actionObject = actionObject;
    }
}
```

Second class

```
 public class Class2 {
    private Long id;
    private int idver;  
    private int valueDate;
}
```

There are  two statement as below,

```
Class1 deserializedValue = (Class1) event.getDeserializedValue();

Class2.class.isAssignableFrom(deserializedValue.getActionObject().getClass());
```

I want to mock the second statement

```
Class2.class.isAssignableFrom(deserializedValue.getActionObject().getClass());
```

how can i do this?

Comment: There are [other ways in Mockito to mock type hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612020/1426891), but is there a reason we need to mock here rather than simply calling `setActionObject()` with a subclass or non-subclass of Class2?

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes you can use a strategy pattern. You just need an interface or an abstract class with two different implementations. One of them is the mock implementation, something like this:

```
public interface EventStrategy {

    // More methods...

    boolean isAssignableFrom(final Object object);

}

public class MyEvent implements EventStrategy {

    public boolean isAssignableFrom(final Object object) {
        return Class2.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass());
    }

}

public class MockEvent implements EventStrategy {

    public boolean isAssignableFrom(final Object object) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `EventStrategy`should be an `interface`, not a simple `class`